# While Concatenating more than two arrays I am not getting the concatenated arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

N,M,P = map(int, input().split())

array_1 = np.array([ map(int, input().split()) for i in range(N) ])

array_2 = np.array([ map(int, input().split()) for i in range(M) ])

print(np.concatenate((array_1, array_2), axis = 0))
```

Comment: Did you look at `array_1` by itself?

Comment: You should tell us what you do get.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
array_1 = np.array([ list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(N) ])


array_2 = np.array([ list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(M) ])
```

The map() here will return an iterator instead of a list. In most cases, this ends up saving memory, and it will give you an object like this :

```
[[<map object at 0x7f385cf48e50> <map object at 0x7f385cf4e430>]]
```